# Parsing JSON in c# return null value

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-2015, json.net, c#-3.0

I am trying to Parse Json in C# . (I am beginner in Json)

```
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
                        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)webRequest;
                        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

                        String responseText = "";
                        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                        {
                            responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
```

//

This is Output in responseText :

```
{
  "disclaimer": "Exchange rates provided for informational purposes only and do not constitute financial advice of any kind. Although every attempt is made to ensure quality, no guarantees are made of accuracy, validity, availability, or fitness for any purpose. All usage subject to acceptance of Terms: https://openexchangerates.org/terms/",
  "license": "Data sourced from various providers; resale prohibited; no warranties given of any kind. All usage subject to License Agreement: https://openexchangerates.org/license/",
  "timestamp": 1454497211,
  "base": "EUR",
  "rates": {
    "INR": 74.42686146,
    "USD": 1.0929332
  }
}
```

To get the base from Json

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(responseText);
String bcur = (string)obj["base"];
Console.WriteLine("base :"bcur.ToString());


Output : base :EUR
```

similarly to get Rates of INR , I wrote

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(responseText);
    String rte= (string)obj["INR"];
    Console.WriteLine("rate:"rte);

it gives me null.
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong in my code. or a better way to get the base and  rate of the currency .

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using `.ToString()` when you are writing out to console when you already specified the type of the variable as a string?

Comment: my bad.. i made a correction .. thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Updated the code in my answer to reflect this too. You are also missing the concatenation character in your console write lines. There should be a `+` between your string and your variable. Or alternatively, if you are using .Net 4.6 you can use the string interpolation stuff by prefixing your string with a $. Using one of your examples `Console.WriteLine("rate:"rte);` would look like `Console.WriteLine($"rate:{rte}");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INR is not in the base object, so you are looking for the `INR` property in a place where it doesn't exist. You would have to go about it in a two step fashion in order to access the property in . Modifiying your code above, it would look something like this:

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(responseText);
JObject rates = (JObject)obj["rates"];
string rte = (string)rates["INR"];
Console.WriteLine("rate:" + rte);
```

Comment: After your answer i realised that there was `rates` also a JObject. Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help :)